# How to send user data to developer in a Swift application?

Tags: swift, database, upload, user-input

I'm creating my first application that requires me to update the app based on user input. I've been searching for the best way to send input to me. For example, I have a button that when the user presses I would like to send me the information they've added to a text field. Being new to this, I thought this could be done by simply sending the information to a specified email, but from what I've researched I will need some sort of database. Looking through the Apple Developer Documentation I don't even know which topic I should be looking at to figure this out, any help or direction would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a server (using an API) to receive the information.

Usually you will use a webservice to receive the info from the app, although there are other ways to do that.

Sending an email through iOs would require the user to accept the email that is being sent, so doesn't look like a good idea.

Take a look at some options available to create webservices (django rest framework or flask), Google's Firebase also can be handy in this situation, since is only integrating it with your app and storing the data you want to store, with easy integration for Authentication and user tracking.